# Need help identifying a font family!

Tags: fonts, font-identification, font-design

[image]

Help needed! :)

We've found this amazing font but we can't figure out what font family it belongs to! Are there any font experts out there that might be able to pin point the font family? We've already tried looking for the font on "What The Font" and similar sites with no luck.

Answer (score 3):

If this is a logo, it's possibly a modified font or custom build. With some modifications to the descender on the ***j***, [Zona Pro Bold](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/intelligent-foundry/zona-pro/) and [Core Sans C 65 Bold](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/s-core/core-sans-c/) are a couple of close options:

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1: Looks like a modified Core to me; Zona is not quite right. The 'r' terminates at a slight angle in the OP's specimen and in yours for Core. I notice also the join with the stem underneath the 'r' and the 'n' matches.

Comment: Agreed, very similar typefaces aside from a few subtle nuances. I was also leaning towards Core as well but I thought either could be a good starting point for modification.

Answer (score 0):

Guys I'm actually looking the font and me and my team and my partners though this font was made just for this purpose... is not a family or a font we think